# Could not find mime-types-2.4.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Ruby version is 2.1.3 and rails version is 4.1.6

When I started code in my office system with the above version bundler ran smooth,

After cloning into my home machine with same version mentioned above, bundler is not running 
and it's ends-up with the following error.

bundle install

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........

Could not find mime-types-2.4.2 in any of the sources

Comment: I get the same error attempting to deploy to heroku.

Answer (score 5):

Run `bundle update mime-types`. They yanked version 2.4.2 for 2.4.3.

As you can see, 2.4.2 is missing here: https://rubygems.org/gems/mime-types

Comment: I’m not clear why it wouldn’t work on Heroku—if you update the Gemfile.lock and commit, then you should be able to deploy.

Answer (score 3):

As @allaire says, I pulled mime-types 2.4.2 because it broke a supported platform (Ruby 1.9.2). I did so *after* releasing mime-types 2.4.3.

Why? Because rest-client uses mime-types, and it supports both mime-types 1 and mime-types 2 (because mime-types 2 does not support Ruby 1.8). Even though I do not test against Ruby 1.9.2 on Travis (various reasons, including availability), I still *support* Ruby 1.9.2 until mime-types 3. The rest-client version dependency is `>= 1.16, < 3.0`; because of this, anyone using Ruby 1.9.2 needed it to say `>= 1.16, < 3.0, != 2.4.2`. RubyGems does not—as far as I know—support a `!=` version restriction, and the only way to enforce that is to make it so that 2.4.2 is not available for install by `yank`ing it.

I’m sorry that this happened, and in general, this shouldn’t happen again because I now have a Vagrant VM with Ruby 1.9.2 running to be able to run some tests, since I can’t do that effectively on Travis.

Comment: Based on comments here and elsewhere, I have unyanked 2.4.2. If you are using Ruby 1.9.2, you *must* use 2.4.1 or 2.4.3.

Comment: I did rvm reload, bundle update mime-types, 2.4.3 is in my gemfile.lock, bundle list shows it, yet I still get could not find mime-types 2.4.3 when loading the environment on a development machine

Comment: well after switching from ruby 2.1.2p95 to 2.1.3 and running bundle install, the problem disappeared. Apparently it's some rvm thing.